# How to see how efficient a branch predictor is after designing one?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

I want to design a branch predictor and then test it to see how efficient it is. The question is: how to test them? Are there data sets available?

Comment: You can always do formal analysis, but it's often hard.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? The significance of area and energy costs is relative to total costs (i.e., including those for the rest of the processor) and to the energy saving and performance improvement compared to other mechanisms. The framework from the 2016 Branch Prediction Championship would be one option that would allow easier comparison to some state-of-the-art predictors, though access requires joining the [CBP 2016 Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cbp_2016).

Answer (score 1):

One standard way to evaluate a branch predictor is to implement it in a CPU simulator, and then execute standard benchmarks (e.g., the SPEC benchmark) and see what fraction of branches it has predicted correctly on taht workload.

Comment: SimpleScalar might be a good bet. http://www.simplescalar.com

Comment: I'd say a "standard benchmark" is much too specific. Write a simulator for an Android phone, and use everything that phone does as the workload.